# objective-c accented characters inside a url request

Tags: objective-c, ipad, character-encoding

My app connects itself to a server asking for data do a php script and shows these data on a table.
When I select a row the datails are shown with the full text.
I can read everything correctly on the iPhone and iPad display, but I can modify this text and when I send it to another php script it reads àìùòèé characters not correctly.

The request is sent in this way

`NSMutableURLRequest *richiesta = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sito.it/iosphp/trame.php"]
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[richiesta setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[richiesta setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"trama=%@", self.trama.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

Inside the database (its collation is UTF8) I see √É¬® and other strange things.

How do I manage those characters correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The default Content-Type of a post is [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). This means that you need to percent encode the value you are sending over.

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"trama=%@", [self.trama.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

àìùòèé now becomes %C3%A0%C3%AC%C3%B9%C3%B2%C3%A8%C3%A9